# How to make angular display an empty <p> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm using ng-repeat and am trying to create a paragraph element that has a specific border on hovering, even when the element itself is empty. However, when the paragraph element is empty, there's no hover functionality. And the "inspect element" tool is not showing the presence of a paragraph tag at all.

Is there a workaround?

Thank you.

JS:

```
var members = 
[
 {name: "John", dod: "December 8, 1980"},
 {name: "Paul", dod: ""},
 {name: "George", dod: "November 29, 2001"},
 {name: "Ringo", dod: ""}
];
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat='member in members'>
    <p class='hoveroutline' ng-repeat="member in members">
      {{member.dod}}
    </p>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.hoveroutline:hover{
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You put `p` element inside `tr`. This is invalid markup, and browser will for sure refuse render it like you expect. Use `td` (or `th`) as direct child of the `tr`.

You should rethink your layout: maybe you don't really need table, and you can go with `div`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Try something that uses divs instead of tr, and then you can give every div that class
(also, you're calling ng-repeat twice, which I don't think you want to do)

```
<div class="hoveroutline" >
    <p ng-repeat="member in members">
      {{member.dod}}
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what was said above, ng-repeat will not render anything if it's empty, a solution around it is to have an empty p paragraph that's only visible when members is empty

```
<p ng-repeat="member in members">
    {{member.dod}}
</p>
<p ng-show="!members || members.length === 0"></p>
```

Good luck.